# Why label overLapping on text box in win form c# while generating dynamic text box and label?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
try
{
    int txtno = 10;

    int Textbox_pointY = 15;
    int label_pointY = 15;

    int label_pointX = 10;
    int Textbox_pointX = 75;

    panel1.Controls.Clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < txtno; i++)
    {   //Lable creation

        Label lbl = new Label();
        panel1.Controls.Add(lbl);
        lbl.Text = "Test_" + i;
        lbl.Location = new Point(label_pointX, label_pointY);

        label_pointY += 22;
        //Text box creating 
        TextBox a = new TextBox();
        panel1.Controls.Add(a);
        a.Text = (i + 1).ToString();
        a.Location = new Point(Textbox_pointX, Textbox_pointY);

        //panel1.Show();
        Textbox_pointY += 22;
        //label_pointY += 5;
    }
}
catch (Exception)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
}
```

When dynamically generate label and `enter code here`text box in winform c# Label overlaps over textbox .I need to keep text box closely to label text .I have added my code here .

Comment: If you create a Label the `AutoSize` property is set to `true` by default. Set it to `false` and it would be be better to work with a `FlowLayoutPanel` to arrange controls within a form.

Comment: When you create dynamic controls in the loop - good sign to consider `DataGridView` control. Especially when you using simple `Label` and `TextBox`

Comment: There is simply too much text in the Label.  Consider AutoSize = false and setting the Width property so it can never overlap the TextBox.  Or you can set its MaximumSize property and leave enough room so the text can be wrapper vertically.  Do beware that panel1.Controls.Clear() is a very nasty bug, those controls live for the lifetime of the program.  You *must* call the Dispose() method for these controls.  Instead use while (panel1.Controls.Count > 0) panel1.Controls[0].Dispose();

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4471982/17034

Answer (score 1):

Set `AutoSize` to `false` and specify labels' `Width` explicitly:

```
  int txtno = 10;

  int label_pointY = 15;
  int label_pointX = 10;
  int Textbox_pointX = 75;

  // Don't do this: it just removes conrols from the panel, 
  // but does't free resources (and you have resource leakage)
  // panel1.Controls.Clear();

  // If you want to get rid of all controls on the panel1 (i.e. dispose them) 
  // do it like this:  
  for (int i = panel1.Controls.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i)
    panel1.Controls[i].Dispose();

  for (int i = 0; i < txtno; i++) {
    Label lbl = new Label() {
      Parent = panel1,
      Text = "Test_" + i,
      Location = new Point(label_pointX, label_pointY),
      AutoSize = false,                      
      Width = Textbox_pointX - label_pointX, 
    };

    TextBox box = new TextBox() {
      Parent = panel1,
      Text = (i + 1).ToString(),
      Location = new Point(Textbox_pointX, label_pointY)
    };

    label_pointY += Math.Max(box.Height, lbl.Height);
  }
```

Comment: Please fix the panel1.Controls.Clear() bug, it will get too many programmers in trouble.

Comment: @Hans Passant: Thank you! Resource leakage (HWND in the case) is a real trouble, I'm sorry for my copy paste